# Issues with vertex ai endpoint

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Im having some issues accessing vertex ai endpoints for predictions.

iv created multiple serivces accounts with every role i can think off, but i keep getting the following error:

`PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on resource project ('7*****',). [links { description: "Google developers console" url: "https://console.developers.google.com" } , reason: "CONSUMER_INVALID" domain: "googleapis.com" metadata { key: "consumer" value: "projects/(\'7*****\',)" } metadata { key: "service" value: "aiplatform.googleapis.com" } ]`

maybe im missing something with the roles... I would greatly appreciate the help

I was expecting to get my predictions

Comment: You have provided no details to help you. 1) show the code and the endpoint you are accessing. 2) show the IAM roles assigned to the service account that your code is using.